# Microsoft Excel - Filter rows where Column B> Column C

Tags: excel-formula, excel-2007

This one might be a trivial one:

I have an excel with three columns
Column A - Date
Column B- Values
Column C - Values

I want to view only the rows where Column B value > Value of Column C

Have tried conditional formatting and custom filter, however didnt succeed. Very likely that am not doing in the correct way. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a fourth column, put `=IF(B# > C#,"TRUE","FALSE")`. 
Then select all four columns, go to ***Data*** > ***Filter***, then filter based on *TRUE*.